# Where to set window size iOS in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rootviewcontroller

[image]

I am trying to figure out where set the window bounds. Currently view does not fill the entire screen.

I am just beginning to understand UI design for iOS. I have not set a rootViewController in the app delegate nor have i instantiated a navigation controller in which my view is embedded in.

I have tried using this the code below inside the didFinishLaunching method in appDelegate.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.rootVC= [[LaunchViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController =  self.rootVC;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Can someone help me understand why this is showing my view. IF i remove the added coded and just leave the return YES, my view loads but just as the picture i posted.

[image]

EDIT:

I need the label, and table view to extend across the entire screen and not just in the top left corner. I have no idea why it gets loaded like this and not across the entire screen.. Please help

Comment: Why are you replace `window` property in AppDelegate? Remove the first line and try again

Comment: @Tj3n I tried still loading a blank view. When i run my app on an ipad it doesnt fill the entire screen, other view controllers are full screen except my launch view

Comment: Blank view is more likely because of your `[[LaunchViewController alloc] init];`, It init the viewcontroller without storyboard or xib or haven't implement `loadView`

Comment: @Tj3n  I do not have a loadView, i have a viewdidload method. The problem is my view and my UI elements arent sized correctly on the first view (launchViewController).

Comment: Are you trying to init view from Storyboard or Xib?

Comment: @Tj3n Storyboard, my LauchViewController is embedded in a navigation controller which is set as the initial view controller

Comment: Why do you need your piece of code while you already set initial viewcontroller in your storyboard? Custom drawing? It will be automatically show without any code

Comment: @Tj3n The view is not loading to the correct size. When running on ipad you get the layout pictured above. It is only loading the view only on the top left corner and not across the full ipad screen.

Comment: @Tj3n I am trying to just make sure it adjusts to the full size of the ipad screen on launch, right now i believe it might be referencing an iphone screen size?

Comment: Dont need to, its automatically, unless you change the default setting in your storyboard/app settings/ or dont add necessary constraint

Comment: @Tj3n I dont think so, the view does not get loaded to correct size. Maybe I need to set the bounds or something for the LaunchViewController. I've read about the autoresizingmask but have no idea where and how to use it.

Comment: did you check your constrains?

Comment: @vp2698 No, do you have any resources that would help-me set this accordingly for different devices?

Comment: There are many way to set it You can refer Ray wenderlichs tutorial for it https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: @vp2698 theres no way to just set views based on the device launching. I was hoping UI design would just reposition and set larger images with better resolution based on the device using something like UIWindow

Comment: sorry but i am not getting what you main issue is

Comment: @vp2698 Take a look at my edit, ive been looking for hours now and no solution yet

Answer (score 2):

this is not something about size of the window. this is about the size of the components you put into window.

if you are using storyboard, you have to give some constraints to your views.

you can check this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html